# Interactive pixel information of an image

Tags: python, image, image-processing, matplotlib, scikit-image

**Short version:** is there a Python method for displaying an image which shows, in real time, the pixel indices and intensities?  So that as I move the cursor over the image, I have a continually updated display such as `pixel[103,214] = 198` (for grayscale) or `pixel[103,214] = (138,24,211)` for rgb?

**Long version:**

Suppose I open a grayscale image saved as an ndarray `im` and display it with `imshow` from matplotlib:

```
im = plt.imread('image.png')
plt.imshow(im,cm.gray)
```

What I get is the image, and in the bottom right of the window frame, an interactive display of the pixel indices.  Except that they're not quite, as the values are not integers: `x=134.64   y=129.169` for example.

If I set the display with correct resolution:

```
plt.axis('equal')
```

the x and y values are still not integers.

The `imshow` method from the `spectral` package does a better job:

```
import spectral as spc
spc.imshow(im)
```

Then in the bottom right I now have `pixel=[103,152]` for example.

However, none of these methods also shows the pixel values.  So I have two questions:

1. Can the `imshow` from `matplotlib` (and the `imshow` from `scikit-image`) be coerced into showing the correct (integer) pixel indices?
2. Can any of these methods be extended to show the pixel values as well?

Answer (score 49):

There a couple of different ways to go about this.

You can monkey-patch `ax.format_coord`, similar to [this official example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/image_zcoord.html).  I'm going to use a slightly more "pythonic" approach here that doesn't rely on global variables.  (Note that I'm assuming no `extent` kwarg was specified, similar to the matplotlib example.  To be fully general, you need to do [a touch more work](https://github.com/joferkington/mpldatacursor/blob/master/mpldatacursor/pick_info.py#L27).)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Formatter(object):
    def __init__(self, im):
        self.im = im
    def __call__(self, x, y):
        z = self.im.get_array()[int(y), int(x)]
        return 'x={:.01f}, y={:.01f}, z={:.01f}'.format(x, y, z)

data = np.random.random((10,10))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(data, interpolation='none')
ax.format_coord = Formatter(im)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Alternatively, just to plug one of my own projects, you can use [`mpldatacursor`](https://github.com/joferkington/mpldatacursor) for this.  If you specify `hover=True`, the box will pop up whenever you hover over an enabled artist.  (By default it only pops up when clicked.)  Note that `mpldatacursor` does handle the `extent` and `origin` kwargs to `imshow` correctly.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpldatacursor

data = np.random.random((10,10))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(data, interpolation='none')

mpldatacursor.datacursor(hover=True, bbox=dict(alpha=1, fc='w'))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Also, I forgot to mention how to show the pixel indices.  In the first example, it's just assuming that `i, j = int(y), int(x)`. You can add those in place of `x` and `y`, if you'd prefer.

With `mpldatacursor`, you can specify them with a custom formatter.  The `i` and `j` arguments are the correct pixel indices, regardless of the `extent` and `origin` of the image plotted.

For example (note the `extent` of the image vs. the `i,j` coordinates displayed):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpldatacursor

data = np.random.random((10,10))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(data, interpolation='none', extent=[0, 1.5*np.pi, 0, np.pi])

mpldatacursor.datacursor(hover=True, bbox=dict(alpha=1, fc='w'),
                         formatter='i, j = {i}, {j}\nz = {z:.02g}'.format)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27704490/interactive-pixel-information-of-an-image-in-python#27707723  and links there in.  I think this is a better answer than any of the other ones.  Can you mark all of them as duplicates of this one (I have already voted on most of them before I had 1-vote duplicate close)?

Comment: And can you put in a PR to change the official example to use the `Formatter` class?

Comment: @tcaswell - Done on the close votes.  (And thanks!) If any of those seem significantly different from this question, feel free to re-open them.  I'll put in a PR for the example later tonight.

Comment: Is mpldatacursor supposed to work for two subplots? I tried and got very strange results. I get a cursor box simultaneously over both subplots.

Comment: @YonatanSimson - Yes, it should work.  However, I think your problem might be related to a bug I just fixed a couple of days ago: https://github.com/joferkington/mpldatacursor/commit/9eaca06b65d1a202b914bc990419717ede1e83ff  If you have a chance, you might try reinstalling from the current github master.  Sorry about that!

Comment: I reinstalled using pip install mpldatacurser. My code looks like this: plt.figure()
plt.subplot(121)
plt.imshow(img_a, interpolation='none')
plt.subplot(122)
plt.imshow(img_a, interpolation='none')
mpldatacursor.datacursor(hover=True, bbox=dict(alpha=1, fc='w'), formatter='i, j = {i}, {j}\nz = {z:.02f}'.format)
plt.show(). The curser jumps from subplot to subplot. Perhaps I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Please notice that rows and columns are inverted when it comes to displaying a two-dimensional numpy array. On matplotlib X increases from left to right, however this is normally the same row in a numpy image. Please be aware of these subtlety

Comment: Note that the first example is incorrect by half a pixel. It should rather be `z = self.im.get_array()[int(y+0.5), int(x+0.5)]`.

Answer (score 6):

An absolute bare-bones "one-liner" to do this: (without relying on `datacursor`)

```
def val_shower(im):
    return lambda x,y: '%dx%d = %d' % (x,y,im[int(y+.5),int(x+.5)])

plt.imshow(image)
plt.gca().format_coord = val_shower(ims)
```

It puts the image in closure so makes sure if you have multiple images each will display its own values.

Answer (score 0):

All of the examples that I have seen only work if your x and y extents start from 0. Here is code that uses your image extents to find the z value.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

d = np.array([[i+j for i in range(-5, 6)] for j in range(-5, 6)])
im = ax.imshow(d)
im.set_extent((-5, 5, -5, 5))

def format_coord(x, y):
    """Format the x and y string display."""
    imgs = ax.get_images()
    if len(imgs) > 0:
        for img in imgs:
            try:
                array = img.get_array()
                extent = img.get_extent()

                # Get the x and y index spacing
                x_space = np.linspace(extent[0], extent[1], array.shape[1])
                y_space = np.linspace(extent[3], extent[2], array.shape[0])

                # Find the closest index
                x_idx= (np.abs(x_space - x)).argmin()
                y_idx= (np.abs(y_space - y)).argmin()

                # Grab z
                z = array[y_idx, x_idx]
                return 'x={:1.4f}, y={:1.4f}, z={:1.4f}'.format(x, y, z)
            except (TypeError, ValueError):
                pass
        return 'x={:1.4f}, y={:1.4f}, z={:1.4f}'.format(x, y, 0)
    return 'x={:1.4f}, y={:1.4f}'.format(x, y)
# end format_coord

ax.format_coord = format_coord
```

If you are using PySide/PyQT here is an example to have a mouse hover tooltip for the data

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Qt4Agg")
matplotlib.rcParams["backend.qt4"] = "PySide"
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Mouse tooltip
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
mouse_tooltip = QtGui.QLabel()
mouse_tooltip.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
mouse_tooltip.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.ToolTip)
mouse_tooltip.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TransparentForMouseEvents)
mouse_tooltip.show()

def show_tooltip(msg):
    msg = msg.replace(', ', '\n')
    mouse_tooltip.setText(msg)

    pos = QtGui.QCursor.pos()
    mouse_tooltip.move(pos.x()+20, pos.y()+15)
    mouse_tooltip.adjustSize()
fig.canvas.toolbar.message.connect(show_tooltip)


# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

with Jupyter you can do so either with `datacursor(myax)`or by `ax.format_coord`.

Sample code:

```
%matplotlib nbagg

import numpy as np  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = 10*np.random.rand(5,3)

fig,ax = plt.subplots()    
myax = ax.imshow(X, cmap=cm.jet,interpolation='nearest')
ax.set_title('hover over the image')

datacursor(myax)

plt.show()
```

the `datacursor(myax)` can also be replaced with `ax.format_coord = lambda x,y : "x=%g y=%g" % (x, y)`

Comment: datacurser is not defined, please eloborate your answer

Answer (score 0):

In case you, like me, work on Google Colab, this solutions do not work as Colab disabled interactive feature of images for matplotlib.
Then you might simply use Plotly:
https://plotly.com/python/imshow/

```
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
img_rgb = np.array([[[255, 0, 0], [0, 255, 0], [0, 0, 255]],
                [[0, 255, 0], [0, 0, 255], [255, 0, 0]]
               ], dtype=np.uint8)
fig = px.imshow(img_rgb)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: For me this only shows x and y but not color

Comment: nvm, I had the values standardized in float32 0 - 1, but in order to show color info you need 0 - 255 in uint 8

Answer (score 0):

[image: pixel value at the corner]

Matplotlib has built-in interactive plot which logs pixel values at the corner of the screen.

To setup first install `pip install ipympl`

Then use either `%matplotlib notebook` or `%matplotlib widget` instead of `%matplotlib inline`

The drawback with `plotly` or `Bokeh` is that they don't work on Pycharm.

For more information take a look at the [doc](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/interactive.html)

Answer (score -1):

To get interactive pixel information of an image use the module imagetoolbox
To download the module open the command prompt and write

> pip install imagetoolbox
>   Write the given code to get interactive pixel information of an image
>   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKgc9.png)
>   Output:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBSDN.png)