# How to use IDL visualization routines in Python

Tags: python, idl-programming-language

I have a number of IDL visualization routines which I would prefer to be using in Python. These IDL visualization facilities provided a point-and-click interface with the cursor to see values and positions of pixels.

Is there a Python equivalent to this? If I were to rewrite these routines, how could I provide the same type of visualization facilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Python bridge in IDL 8.5 which would allow you import your visualization routines into Python. Or you could port your visualization routines to a Python visualization library; the most common and general vis library in Python is matplotlib.

Comment: I don't think Python allows you to be as interactive as IDL though. IDL has routines where you can use the mouse cursor to point at images and see values for what's there.

Comment: Sure it can. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27704490/interactive-pixel-information-of-an-image-in-python.