# Change format string of axis picker in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to change the format string (I would like to use `%e`) of the axis picker at the very bottom of images drawn with `matplotlib`.

The image below illustrates which part I would like to alter:

[image]

Comment: Good question, but there is a duplicate [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27704490/interactive-pixel-information-of-an-image-in-python) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14754931/matplotlib-values-under-cursor)

Comment: You're right. I didn't find those. Your first link answered my question and even expanded on it. Thank you for sharing it.