# Change format of coordinate text in status bar

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

Does anyone know how to modify the "x" and "y" in the status bar below a plot?

I want to change it to "Longitude" and "Latitude", is it possible in matplotlib?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Interactive pixel information of an image in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27704490/interactive-pixel-information-of-an-image-in-python)

Answer (score 7):

You can re-assign the `format_coord` method of your Axes, as in the following example (adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14755358/588071) and [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/image_zcoord.html)):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)

ax.pcolormesh(np.random.rand(20,20))

def format_coord(x, y):
    return 'Longitude={:6.3f}, Latitude={:6.3f}'.format(x, y)

ax.format_coord = format_coord

plt.show()
```

Or, in a one-liner, you could use a `lambda` function:

```
ax.format_coord = lambda x, y: "Longitude={:6.3f}, Latitude={:6.3f}".format(x,y)
```

[image]

Comment: Omg! such a great answer, it helped me for my thesis. Many thanks sir tom

Comment: Yes, I think so. See the linked posts