# How to control mouseover text in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, imshow

When you mouseover an image shown with imshow, you can mouseover the image to inspect its RGB values. The bottom-right corner of the matplotlib window (sharing space with the toolbar), shows the image coordinates and RGB values of the pixel being pointed at:

```
x = 274.99  y = 235.584  [.241, .213, .203]
```

However, when I mouseover a quiver plot, it only shows the x and y coords of the pointer, but not the value of the 2D vector being pointed at. Is there a way to get the vector values to show up?

I would be fine with writing a custom mouse event handler, if I only knew how to set that bit of text in the matplotlib window.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There were times when the information about the color value was not present by default. In fact I think the current version is based on some code that came up in Stackoverflow on some question about that feature.

I quickly found those two questions:

- [matplotlib values under cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14754931/matplotlib-values-under-cursor)
- [Interactive pixel information of an image in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27704490/interactive-pixel-information-of-an-image-in-python)

The idea would be to change the function that is called when the mouse hovers the axes. This function is stored in `ax.format_coord`. So a possible solution is to write your custom function to return the desired output based on the input coordinates, e.g. something like

```
def format_coord(x, y):
    try:
        z = # get value depending on x,y, e.g. via interpolation on grid
            # I can't fill this because the kind of data is unknown here
        return "x: {}, y: {}, z: {}".format(x,y,z)

    except:
        return "x: {}, y: {}".format(x,y)

ax.format_coord = format_coord
```